# Groovy - REST API request which needs credential

Tags: rest, api, groovy

I need to make a request to a REST api using Groovy (alas I'm a Groovy novice...) and I need to pass the credentials (user and pwd) to access it when making the request.
The API should then return some JSON which I can parse.

I have seen some snippets of code here and there using HTTPBuilder, but I have not managed to make it work.

Any idea to start from?
I know that we are currently doing this in Python with a POST request, we the get some cookie and then we make a GET request.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use RESTClient, that is a wrapper around HTTPBuilder, but has simplified interface to build REST calls.

[httpbilder RESTClient](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/RESTClient)

Answer (score -1):

What you (probably) want to do, is a [HTTP basic authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617). There is a snippet [here](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/Authentication%20here), which does it using HTTPBuilder.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I will have a look. I know the question was very vague ;)